# Getting the value of brother/sister node

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath, domdocument

Let's say on a page I have alot of this repeated:

```
<div class="entry">
  <h4>Magic:</h4>
  <a>Edit</a> 
  <a>Delete</a>
</div>
```

But the `nodeValue` of `h4` is not repeated. How do I get the `nodeValue` of the `a` based on the `h4` tag's `nodeValue`? Get content of the sister `a` nodes of h4 where h4 content is `Magic:`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this XPath:

```
//div/h4[. = 'Magic:']/following-sibling::a[1]
```

It selects 1<sup>st</sup> following-sibling `a` element of `h4` with value `Magic:`.

Comment: Hi, it's only getting one of the `a` brother/sister node.

Comment: @user1099531, So remove `[1]` predicate.